# docker desktop cannot start at all on windows server 2016

Tags: containers, docker-desktop

On windows server 2016, my docker desktop cannot start at all, with error messages bellow. MobyLinuxVM is running then. I am confused and not sure what to do next. Any ideas are welcome.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Using only 1 cpu. This issue is still open.

https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/2253